# show only year-month-day from a DateTime value

Tags: scala, jodatime

I have this code:

```
order.bookingDate()
```

and i get this: `2013-11-22T10:15:00.000-08:00`

But I just want to show this: `2013-11-22` in the webpage, and if it's possible in this format: `22-11-2013`, any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) object:

```
val fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
fmt.print(order.bookingDate())
```

You can save `DateTimeFormat` object in `object` field as a global constant, it is thread-safe. Or you can use `toString()` method directly:

```
order.bookingDate().toString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

See `DateTimeFormat` API documentation (link above) for more information on possible date/time patterns. For example, this format: `22-11-2013` is easily achieved by reversing formatting pattern in previous example:

```
order.bookingDate().toString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

If you have date time in string then first convert it to datetime as follows

```
DateTime dateTime;
dateTime = new DateTime();
dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", null);
```

**Formats for Date**

```
d - Numeric day of the month without a leading zero.
dd - Numeric day of the month with a leading zero.
ddd - Abbreviated name of the day of the week.
dddd - Full name of the day of the week.

M - Numeric month with no leading zero.
MM - Numeric month with a leading zero.
MMM - Abbreviated name of month.
MMMM - Full month name.

y - Year with out century and leading zero.
yy - Year with out century, with leading zero.
yyyy - Year with century.
```

**Formats for Time**

```
h - 12 Hour clock, no leading zero.
hh - 12 Hour clock with leading zero.
H - 24 Hour clock, no leading zero.
HH - 24 Hour clock with leading zero.

m - Minutes with no leading zero.
mm - Minutes with leading zero.

s - Seconds with no leading zero.
ss - Seconds with leading zero.

t - AM/PM but only the first letter. 
tt - AM/PM ( a.m. / p.m.)

zz - Time zone off set with +/-
```

Comment: datetime doesn't have a "ToString" method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to pattern match and get what you want. Eg:

```
val rawDate = "2013-11-22T10:15:00.000-08:00" //order.bookingDate() or order.bookingDate().toString

val YMD = """(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d).*""".r // Three capture groups of 4,2, and 2 digits, followed by stuff we don't care about ('.*')

val YMD(y, m, d) = rawDate // unapply to store the captured groups into new vals y, m, d

val outStr = s"$d-$m-$y" // outStr = "22-11-2013"
```

Comment: It is somewhat strange to use double-step transformation involving regular expressions when there already are tools for it :)

Comment: The date she has isn't a string, it's a Joda `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Simply use your format in ToString() method:

```
order.bookingDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Joda,

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
val dt = new DateTime("2013-11-22T10:15:00.000-08:00")
```

Then

```
dt.toYearMonthDay.toString
String = 2013-11-22
```

and

```
dt2.getDayOfMonth + "-" + dt2.getMonthOfYear + "-" + dt2.getYear
String = 22-11-2013
```

Answer (score 0):

`` from datetime import datetime
- `datetime.now()`
Expected Output : 2018-11-15T11:14:00.000-08:00
Need only date: 
- `datetime.date(datetime.now())` ``

If you need to strip the date or year or time and arrange them as per your requirements. Play around adjusting the values in which ever place you want.
you can do the following:

`` - `datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")`
Expected Output: YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM
'2018-11-15-11-14' ``